Is each representation induced by a simpler representation
Let $G$ be a finite group, $V$ be a real vector space of dimension $N$, and $N > |G|$.
Can you find a representation $\sigma: G \to GL(\text{End}(V))$ such that $\sigma$ is not induced by a representation $\rho: G \to GL(V)$ via $\sigma_g(X)=\rho_g^{-1}X\rho_g$; $g \in G$ and $X \in GL(V)$?
We know each automorphism of $GL(\text{End}(V))$ is inner. That is, for each $g \in G$, there exists $U_g \in GL(V)$ such that $\sigma_g(X)=U_g^{-1}XU_g$. Does this necessitate the existant of $\rho: G \to GL(V)$ such that $\rho_g =U_g$ when $N> |G|$?

$GL(GL(V))$ does not make sense as far as I know.

@CaptainLama I believe it should really be $GL(\operatorname{End}(V))$

Were the answer to the question in your title yes, then there would have to be an infinite sequence of ever-simpler representations.

You don't even mean $GL(\text{End}(V))$ but $\text{Aut}(\text{End}(V))$, right? That is I assume you're not interested in representations which don't preserve the multiplication (which clearly cannot be induced by conjugation but for simpler reasons).

Would you explain what the differences between GL(algebra) and Aut(algebra) is? I thought they were the same. I once asked which notation is better between $\sigma: G \to GL(S^N)$ and $\sigma: G \to Aut(S^N)$, where $S^N$ is the space of $N \times N$ symmetric matrices, and you said the later is awkward.

I assume you mean $\text{Aut}(\text{End}(V))$. By the Skolem-Noether theorem this is $PGL(V)$, so your question is whether every map $G \to PGL(V)$ lifts to a map $G \to GL(V)$.
This is well-understood. Maps $G \to PGL(V)$ are called projective representations, and whether they lift to $GL(V)$ is controlled by whether a corresponding cohomology class in $H^2(G, K^{\times})$ vanishes. This class is sometimes called the Schur multiplier but that name also refers to several other closely related objects; it should really be called something like the Schur class. It is the cohomology class you get when you try to lift each individual element of $G$ and compare the difference between the lift of $gh$ and the product of the lifts of $g$ and $h$.
The condition on the dimension of $V$ is irrelevant because the Schur class doesn't change when you add a genuine representation.
A typical way to produce nontrivial examples of projective representations is to take genuine representations of a central extension
$$1 \to Z \to H \to G \to 1$$
of $G$ on which the center $Z$ acts by scalars (it's a classical fact that every projective representation of a finite group arises in this way), which means the induced map $H \to PGL(V)$ has kernel $Z$ and hence gives a map $G \to PGL(V)$ which usually won't lift to $GL(V)$.
The smallest nontrivial central extension is the quaternion group $Q_8$, which is a central extension of $V_4$ by $C_2$. It has a unique $4$-dimensional irreducible representation $\mathbb{R}^4 \cong \mathbb{H}$ induced by the inclusion $Q_8 \hookrightarrow \mathbb{H}$, on which the center acts by $-1$. This gives a projective representation $V_4 \to PGL_4(\mathbb{R})$ which does not lift to $GL_4(\mathbb{R})$.
To see this explicitly we can think of $Q_8$ as $\{ \pm 1, \pm i, \pm j, \pm k \}$ as a subgroup of $\mathbb{H}$, with center $\pm 1$, so the quotient by the center is $V_4 = \{ 1, i, j, k \}$ with $i, j, k$ all of order $2$. Any lift of the corresponding projective representation $V_4 \to PGL_4(\mathbb{R})$ to $GL_4(\mathbb{R})$ must lift $i, j, k$ to some nonzero real multiples $pi, rj, qk$, but none of these commute.

Can you also provide a counterexample when we work over reals?

@khashayar: $Q_8$ is also a counterexample over the reals, I've just edited.

I see, so helpful.
